# Replicating regression biplot calculations

Tags: regression, biplot

I am working through Chapter 2 of Biplots in Practice (available here: https://www.fbbva.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/dat/greenacre_c02_2010.pdf)

Some of the code is provided in the appendix: https://www.fbbva.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/dat/greenacre_ap0Aok_2010.pdf but not all.

Data is here: http://www.carme-n.org/?sec=data3

I am stumped figuring how the 4.06 on page 30, the projection of the 4th point onto the biplot vector, was calculated. I am not able to reproduce it either graphically or algebraically as predicted value for $d$ despite many hours of efforts. I appreciate your help.